# Rotor rubs caliper after every ride

Tags: disc-brake, adjustment

I've noticed the rotor on my front wheel rubs on the outer caliper's brake pad after I go for a ride.

I've adjusted the wheel alignment a few times just with the quick release mechanism to get the rotor out of contact with the caliper before I head out but every time I get back from a ride it's rubbing again when I spin the wheel.

Is there anything I can adjust to prevent the rubbing re-occurring?

The bike is a 2019 Giant Fastroad SL-1.

Comment: Need to know if its mechanical or hydraulic disks. Caliper alignment would be a good start https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/hydraulic-disc-brake-alignment or https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/mechanical-disc-brake-alignment

Comment: Is your rotor flat or does it have any bend in it when the wheel is spin freely ?

Comment: You need to re-align the callipers in the standard procedure by undoing the bolts, keeping the lever pulled and retightening the bolts.

Comment: Definitely setup the brake around the wheel and not the other way round. If the rotor is bent, realign or replace it. I adjust the "dummy" piston and then set the cable length to get a snug fit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you are adjusting the position of the wheel axle in the frame drop outs to move the rotor relative to the caliper. Your weight and the forces generated going over bumps will push the axle fully into the dropouts, that's why you are getting rub after every ride.

The calipers have an adjustment mechanism and that's how you should adjust the caliper to tune out rub on the rotor. The two mounting bolts go through slots on the caliper which allows the position to be adjusted when the bolts are loosened.

I think you have hydraulic brakes on the Fastroad SL-1. They are slightly easier to adjust that mechanical disc brakes. A good trick for setting hydraulic caliper position is to loosen the bolts so that the caliper can just move, squeeze the brake lever and tighten the bolts (it helps to have a friend squeeze the lever for you).

Park Tool Company has great instruction videos. [Try this one](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/hydraulic-disc-brake-alignment). It also will point you to instructions on mechanical brakes if that's in fact what you have.

Comment: It is also a good idea to replace Giant's quick release skewers with decent ones. For example Shimano XT skewers. The clamping force is higher and it is much easier to get a repeatable and reliable wheel position. Better skewers and very consistent procedure putting my wheel in has reduced my brake rub problems considerably.